# How can I get data from JSON array object with JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I get all the data from the JSON array objects with jquery?
I have tried before but my code only can get the data from the JSON object.

This is my json file *student.json* :

```
{"status":true,
  "offset":0,
  "limit":25,
  "total":2,
  "data":[
    { "id":231,
      "title":"mytitle1",
      "content":"myconten1",
      "created_at":"2017-07-10 03:56:32",
      "updated_at":"2017-07-10 03:56:32"
    },{ "id":230,
        "title":"mytitle2",
        "content":"mycontent2",
        "created_at":"2017-07-10 03:56:06",
        "updated_at":"2017-07-10 03:56:06"
    }]}
```

My js script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function (){
            var $orders = $('#orders');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'json/student.json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('success', data);
                    $.each(data, function(i, dataentry){
                        $orders.append('<li>dataid: '+dataentry.id+'</li>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: you mean your ajax call fail?

Comment: You should read up on the difference between JSON, an object literal in JS and an Array.

Comment: i think it shoild be : data.data[0].id

Comment: i can grab the data with ajax and show it in the console log only, but when i try to show in the html data undifiend @artgb

Comment: can you please share, what you are getting in console upon logging the `data` object ?

Comment: i have tried your suggestion "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" @AnupamSingh

Comment: this from the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" @RaghavGarg

Comment: yes i was read it @lexith

Comment: @indodev28, the error you are showing me, is after the changes suggest by `anupam`, i was asking to share the console result with your own code. Anyways, I believe `lexith` has answered your question.

Comment: to add to my previous comment: if you load a json via jquery ajax, it automatically will parse it to a object literal so it can be used directly in your script via dot notation. Just to make the wording more clear.

Comment: when i'm run the code just showing : "dataid: undefined" in the html, and in the console not show anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So first, you don't need to write this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
             $(function (){
```

Because `$(function()` ( w/o a space ) is a short for `$(document).ready(function()`.

Regarding your issue - I believe that `data` is the entire JSON, so you need to extract `data.data`, so I would write this:

```
$(function (){
    var $orders = $('#orders');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'json/student.json',
        success: function(response) {      // <= this is the change
            var data = response.data;      // <= going inside the data itself
            $.each(data, function(i, data){
                $orders.append('<li>dataid: '+data.id+'</li>');
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: finally i can show the data, with your suggestion, thanks alot

Comment: Awesome, if you can just approve the answer - that would be best ;)

Comment: you're so amazing bro :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `success` function, the `data` received is the actual data response of your ajax call.

You should see it in your `console.log` statement with all properties like `offset`, `limit`, `total` etc.

Anyway, you're trying to loop through the whole object, not the `data` property inside the response, which is actually the array you probably want to loop through. You won't get any errors because `$.each` can loop through object literals as well as through arrays.

Here's how it should look like (i adjusted the variable names to make it clearer):

```
success: function(response) {
    $.each(response.data, function(i, dataEntry){     // or response['data']
         $orders.append('<li>dataid: '+dataEntry.id+'</li>');
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax call is successful, then :

- **function(data) :** this data is the base object returned from server, in your case its not the **data** property.
- now the **data** in your json is an array.

so, instead of using foreach on root object, use it on **data.data**. 
hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/xydqLLdb/

```js
var response = {"status":true,
  "offset":0,
  "limit":25,
  "total":2,
  "data":[
    { "id":231,
      "title":"mytitle1",
      "content":"myconten1",
      "created_at":"2017-07-10 03:56:32",
      "updated_at":"2017-07-10 03:56:32"
    },{ "id":230,
        "title":"mytitle2",
        "content":"mycontent2",
        "created_at":"2017-07-10 03:56:06",
        "updated_at":"2017-07-10 03:56:06"
    }]};
    
$.each(response.data, function(i, data){
  $('ul').append('<li>dataid: ' + data.id + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Based on your scenario

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
 $(function (){
  var $orders = $('#orders');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'json/student.json',
    success: function(response) {
      $.each(response.data, function(i, data){
        $orders.append('<li>dataid: ' + data.id + '</li>');
      });
    }
  });
});
});
```

You need to loop through the `data` `key` with the **repsonse data**.

Hope this will help you.